# Java Connection to Avaya

Tags: java, oracle-adf, avaya

### Problem

I need to interact with the `avaya` phones in a *java* application, I need to receive calls then take action upon caller data.

### Questions

1. How to use `avaya api` with *java* applications?
2. What methods to use to retrieve data?

Comment: this is **off-topic: recommendations** as well.